# Replace string with designated number from file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to mass-replace words with numbers that are assigned to them.

So for example, if `CurrentString` = `dog`, how would I replace it with number 3?

My external file could look something like this (just an example):

```
1,bird
2,cat
3,dog
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Where are you trying to do the replacing?  Perhaps an example of what you actually want would help and where the problem is with what you tried

Comment: Please clarify with a sample input and expected output?

Comment: Sample input will be `dog`, and output will be `3` in a variable. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work if data in file (in my example it's /tmp/file_index) uniq and it's now very big (otherwise you would have big structure in memory):

```
index = {}
with open('/tmp/file_index', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        index[line.split(',')[1].strip()] = line.split(',')[0]


if CurrentString in index.keys():
    CurrentString = index[CurrentString]
```

Comment: Hey Ievgen, so basically what we do is for each string we read the whole file, and if we find the right word we then split the string and extract the number?

Comment: No. You read the file only once and create the mapping.